# How to configure OpenVPN to only listen on given interface?

Tags: openvpn

How can I configure an OpenVPN server on a Linux machine to only listen on given interfaces? Are there any features like this in OpenVPN?

Answer (score 3):

At the start of your sample configuration file (that i suggest to copy from `/usr/share/doc/packages/openvpn or /usr/share/doc/openvpn-2.0`, you have the following:

```
# Which local IP address should OpenVPN
# listen on? (optional)
;local a.b.c.d
```

[Here](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#install) you have a great official installation/configuration guide for OpenVPN, that i suggest you step forward with it since OpenVPN isn't a simple configuration.

Comment: OP wants to specify by interface name, not by IP.  You dont always know your IP at config time  (wired wan or LTE interface)